# How to set widget's PendingIntent after device boot

Tags: android, android-widget

i've been trying to develop a widget and i'm in my final stages, i have only one more obstacle - how to assign a PendingIntent again to the widget after device boot?

i have a BroadcastReceiver that receives the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast:

```
    public static final String TAG = "BootReceiver";
private Context c;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast!");

    Intent readPrefsAfterBoot = new Intent(c, my widget class);
    readPrefsAfterBoot.setAction(* my custom action *);
    c.sendBroadcast(readPrefsAfterBoot);
}
```

my AppWidgetProvider that receives that custom action is like this:

```
    ** reading saved data from SharedPreferences **

                RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), my widget layout);

                AppWidgetManager awm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

                Intent intent = new Intent(context,my widget class);
                intent.setAction(* another custom action *);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
                rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(my button, pi);
                awm.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], rv);
```

it's either not working or force closing for some reason that i can't analyze...

Comment: Try using logs to debug if the broadcast is received and if the intent is called. then restart phone with logcat on.

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to look at LogCat and review the stack trace associated with your "force closing".

Comment: it will take me some time because i have a lot of apps installed and many widgets on my screens....
but in the meantime, is there a possibility that the problem is from the context being used in my widget's class?

Comment: @CommonsWare ok problem, i installed the new version of the widget, i made my app widget provider get boot_completed action, the only problem is that i can't use logcat :|
after i put my widget on the home screen, i go to the command prompt and type adb logcat. it's working fine, but when i restart my device (using widget from app called Quick Boot), then my logcat stops, so i write again 'adb logcat' but it keeps waiting for a device to be connected... solution?

Comment: "using widget from app called Quick Boot" -- please shut the device down normally when testing. "it keeps waiting for a device to be connected" -- that's a problem that I cannot solve. I have never seen that occur for a device that was successfully plugged into USB and working with `adb` before the reboot.

Answer (score 0):

The onUpdate() method is called when the widgets start up the first time after boot, that's where I normally set the PendingIntent in my app.

Also I found that if you have trouble with the PendingIntent (in my case the extra data does not get passed correctly) to just restart the phone.